# menu bar loose its responsiveness after breakpoint

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, navigation

The menu bar didn't resize properly when the browser window size is smaller than 900px. 
The bar remains too wide, some content is off screen and a horizontal scrollbar appears too.

I tried to get this menu bar working for two days now. I cant even point out the problem. I tried everything which came to my mind.

I guess the error is somewhere within the

```
@media screen and (min-width:900px)
```

[here is a pen with all the code because I thought it's too much code to paste here](https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/EvzgQJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add each item below the rest using flexbox-wrap, this will move items to a new line if the space is too small

```
.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/BwyGer)

you can also add margin to the top of the menu to prevent the overflow only on small devices

```
@media (max-width :800px){
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 999999999999999999;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: I did thumbs up but its not showing because of less than 15 rep :(
I think your solution is just the easiest one. I have to play with the z-index? to prevent that the dropdown menu appears behind the menu items in the 2nd line

Comment: yes you can do it with z index or you can add margin top on your menu tab just like the example, .. marked as the correct answer if it helped you ;)